# Difference between a statement and a query in SQL

Tags: sql, database, terminology

I still live in this ambiguity: conceptually what's the difference between a **statement** and a **query** in SQL? Can anybody give a definition for each of them? It would be useful, for example when choosing variables names inside programs in a way that will be clear for everybody.
Thanks!

**ADDITIONALLY:** How can I call a chunk of SQL code made by more than one statement where statements are separated by a semicolon (`;`)? Who already replied can edit his answer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

A *statement* is any text that the database engine recognizes as a valid command. As of `SQL-92`:

> An SQL-statement is a string of characters that conforms to the format and syntax rules specified in this international standard.

A *query* is a statement that returns a recordset (possibly empty).

> How can I call a chunk of SQL code made by more than one statement where statements are separated by a semicolon (;)? Who already replied can edit his answer. Many thanks!

A series of `SQL` statements sent to the server at once is called a *batch*.

Not all `SQL` engines required the statements in a batch to be semicolon delimited. `SQL Server`, for instance, generally does not and breaks the statements based on context. `CTE` statements starting with `WITH` are a notable exception.

Comment: "A statement is any text that the database engine recognizes as a valid command". Please tell difference between command and query.

Comment: So queries are a subset of statements that do not alter the database?

Answer (score 33):

A **statement** is any SQL command such as SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.

A **query** is a synonym for a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 15):

From [Wikipedia - SQL Language Elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)

> The SQL language is sub-divided into several language elements, including:
>
> - *Clauses*, which are constituent components of statements and queries. (In some cases, these are optional.)[9]
> - *Expressions*, which can produce either scalar values or tables consisting of columns and rows of data.
> - *Predicates*, which specify conditions that can be evaluated to SQL three-valued logic (3VL) or Boolean (true/false/unknown) truth values and which are used to limit the effects of statements and queries, or to change program flow.
> - ***Queries***, which retrieve data based on specific criteria.
> - ***Statements***, which may have a persistent effect on schemas and data, or which may control transactions, program flow, connections, sessions, or diagnostics.
>
>   - SQL statements also include the semicolon (";") statement terminator. Though not required on every platform, it is defined as a standard part of the SQL grammar.
> - *Insignificant whitespace* is generally ignored in SQL statements and queries, making it easier to format SQL code for readability.

Comment: I just noticed that the image next to the text you quoted shows an example of a 'SQL query' which includes a modify statement `UPDATE`. Does that mean queries also include data modification too?

Comment: *Statement* is the more generic term and includes *queries*. See the description of the two terms above. The image is misleading in this case. But, actually in everyday programming use I also tend to mix up the two terms and I am using them synonymously.

Answer (score 5):

A *statement* is the general term for a piece of complete, correct SQL that you can send to a DBMS. A *query* is a statement that will return data, thus a query is a special kind of statement.

A `SELECT ...` would be a query, a `DELETE...` just a statement.

Answer (score 3):

They're used interchangeably by most, but some often use the word "query" to mean, specifically, `SELECT` statements, because when you *query* something or someone, you want information. And `SELECT` queries return result sets, so that'd fit the description nicely. This also is evident in the fact that `SELECT` statements are formally called DQL (Data Query Language) statements.

Comment: Is a `SELECT..INTO` (doesn't return a resultset) a query? Is `(VALUES (1)) AS T (col);` (does return a resultset) a query?

Comment: "SELECT statements are formally called DQL" -- I think the use of DML. DDL, DCL, etc are informal. Who is the trusted source for such matters? I've seen various definitions of DCL. `SELECT` is normally associated with DML, IMO. I don't think DQL is commonly used, other than to mean Doctrine Query Language or a typo for SQL (consider that the D key is next to the S key).

Answer (score 1):

**Queries** is used for retrieve data based on specific criteria, but **statement** may have a persistent effect on schemas and data, or which may control transactions, program flow, connections, sessions, or diagnostics. See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Language_elements).