# Is there valid statement that don’t return a recordset?

Tags: sql, standards, definition

In the question [Difference between a statement and a query in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735856/difference-between-a-statement-and-a-query-in-sql), [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4735902/274188) says:

> A statement is any text that the database engine recognizes as a valid command.

and

> A query is a statement that returns a recordset (possibly empty).

For example, I know that `update` and `insert` can return a recorset when they use a `returning` clause, so I guess they return an empty returnset in the other case. Also, according to the postgres documentation, the `update` command returns a “command tag”. But I don’t understand if the tag is attached to an empty recordset or if it’s really all that is returned.

My question is: Considering [this list of SQL commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html), how do I know which one does not a return a resultset (not even an empty one) and what are they returning instead exactly?

Comment: There are many statements that do not return record sets. `update`, `begin` `create table`, `drop table`, `add index`, etc etc. Enumerating all of them is out of scope for a Stack Overflow answer. Please limit your questions to one actual question per post.

Comment: @meagar I think `update` returns a resultset, cause depending on your database you can do `update ... returning col1, col2`. so my was that it returned an empty resultset when `returning` is absent

Answer (score 1):

Generally accepted version is that

- Query(ies) are select statement which may or may not return rows
  but does not make any changes to database.
- Statement(s) are instructions when executed and successful will make
  changes in the database(after commit)