# What is the difference between Retrieve and Query in DB?

Tags: database

I don't know the difference between `Retrieve` and `Query` in the field of Database. I learnt that `query` means that the user asks the DBMS for some info, but the `retrieve` operation seems to mean the same thing. I'm new to the DB. What are the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a perspective of user of the database, there is not difference at all. `Retrieve` is interchangeable with `Query`. When you want to retrieve data from database you will execute a query that will return the data. So as a developer, the difference is irrelevant.

Difference arrives from the perspective of the database. To query for the database means to parse the query statement, written in a query language, to compile the query in an executable code, to prepare the compiled code for execution and to schedule the execution. In this way, the database creates a `cursor` that will be used to `fetch` the data. Retrieve in this context means to travel trough the cursor, read the data and return it to the client.

Note that in this context, the query statement can also be used to store data in the database, and in this case, the cursor will return calculated fields or ids of the modified rows (depending from the database engine).

Read more from from wikipedia about [Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) and [Data retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_retrieval)

Answer (score 1):

From [Difference between a statement and a query in SQL - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735856/difference-between-a-statement-and-a-query-in-sql):

> A **query** is a synonym for a SELECT statement.

From [SQL example statements for retrieving data from a table](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahux):

> An SQL SELECT statement **retrieves** records from a database table

From [SQL - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL):

> **Queries**, which **retrieve** the data based on specific criteria

**Query** typically means **retrieve** data so the terms are interchangeable. I have also seen query to also include data retrieval *and* manipulation. Interestingly, even in the same Wikipedia article as above, query includes `UPDATE` (modify records):

[image: SQL query]

Answer (score 0):

> Retrieve means to get back things done earlier while query means to ask to do.
> Can like when using Pagination Data if we what you get data from 2nd Page you Retrieve from Same Database Table.

I think this might help you!!!