# Mito and SXQL: count with select-dao?

Tags: common-lisp

With Mito and SxQL, we have `count-dao 'model`, which doesn't accept a `(sxql:select …)` clause.

How can we use a `(select-dao 'model)`, our `select` to filter results, and count the number of rows?

For example, I'd like to count this:

```lisp
(mito:select-dao 'loan
    (sxql:where (:< :due-date (local-time:now))))
```

- https://github.com/fukamachi/sxql/
- https://github.com/fukamachi/mito/

Answer (score 1):

That should do:

```
(sxql:select
    ((:as (:count :*) :count))
  (sxql:from (sxql:make-sql-symbol (mito.class.table:table-name (find-class 'user))))
  (sxql:where
   (:< :due-date (local-time:now))))
;; => #<SXQL-STATEMENT: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM user WHERE (due-date < '2021-10-05 00:27:23.010665')>
```

The `(mito.class.table:table-name (find-class 'user))` part is to convert from a symbol representing th DAO to a string which contains the actual name of the SQL table.

Then you pass the name of the table to `sxql:make-sql-symbol` to make the string usable by `sxql`.

EDIT:

If you want to have the date format "YYYY-MM-DD", you can do

```lisp
(local-time:format-timestring
 nil                    ; output to string
 (local-time:now)
 :format local-time:+iso-8601-date-format+) ; using  a pre-defined format
```

Comment: Thank you! It's a good start. So that returns a SXQL statement that I have to `yield`.

Comment: But `yield` is not enough, I have to execute this query somehow. `dbi:execute`, `dbi:prepare`…

Comment: Also, `local-time:now` won't do, it should be formatted to `"2021-10-05"`.

Comment: I edited the answer to show how one can use `local-time` to create a date with the right format.

Comment: thanks again, but actually I'm mostly looking how to execute this generated sxql statement. Forgot and it's not obvious either.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some experimenting with this myself, the first discovery I made was that there's two functions in the mito package: [execute-sql](https://github.com/fukamachi/mito/blob/6835d2c8120454e93c69d4f22cccb10d9ee24526/src/core/db.lisp#L117) and [retrieve-by-sql](https://github.com/fukamachi/mito/blob/6835d2c8120454e93c69d4f22cccb10d9ee24526/src/core/db.lisp#L163).

The distinction may be obvious to anyone who knows SQL well, but to be explicitly clear in SQL there's a [difference between a statement and a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735856/difference-between-a-statement-and-a-query-in-sql).

The `execute-sql` function appears to be used to execute statements, and the `retrieve-by-sql` appears to be used for running queries, at least, I have some code that supports my assertion.

Please Note: I do not know if any of what I discovered is considered best practice with the mito library or not, only that I got it working.

---

*execute-sql*

Statements concerned with modifying the database without actually returning any data beyond what is presumably a status code can be used with `execute-sql`.

I tested the following code and was able to create and delete a table using this method.

```
(mito:execute-sql "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (name TEXT)")
(mito:execute-sql "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1")
```

---

*retrieve-by-sql*

If one wants to actually retrieve data from the database, it would appear that `retrieve-by-sql` is the function to use.

A *very* basic example of using the function is as follows, one can write a raw sql query and bind values safely using the `:binds` keyword argument.

```
(mito:retrieve-by-sql "SELECT ? + ?" :binds '(3 3))
=> ((:|? + ?| 6))
```

Slightly awkward but it did add 3 to itself, so I got curious, and wanted to see what more I could do with it.

```
(mito:retrieve-by-sql "SELECT ? + ? AS res" :binds '(3 3))
=> ((:RES 6))
```

This is *much* closer to what we might want. Doing a simple `SELECT` like this, the results are a little messy, because we get a list of rows back, so to get the value, we need to use a combination of `car` and `getf`, like so:

```
(getf (car (mito:retrieve-by-sql "SELECT ? + ? AS res" :binds '(3 3))) :res)
=> 6 (3 bits, #x6, #o6, #b110)
```

I hope you now see the pattern for using these functions, so a slightly more complex (but realistic) example is below. I have a simple table and I want to get some data out of it.

```
(mito:retrieve-by-sql "SELECT * FROM collection WHERE user_id = ?" :binds '(1))
=> ((:ID 3828 :USER-ID 1 :CARD-ID "00006596-1166-4a79-8443-ca9f82e6db4e" :QUANTITY
  1)
 (:ID 4272 :USER-ID 1 :CARD-ID "0002ab72-834b-4c81-82b1-0d2760ea96b0" :QUANTITY
  4))
```

Now, `sxql` has a lot of convenience functions to write nicer, more lispier code, so let's see what the previous example might look like using those:

```
(mito:retrieve-by-sql (sxql:select (:*) (sxql:from :collection) (sxql:where (:= :user_id 1))))
=> ((:ID 3828 :USER-ID 1 :CARD-ID "00006596-1166-4a79-8443-ca9f82e6db4e" :QUANTITY
  1)
 (:ID 4272 :USER-ID 1 :CARD-ID "0002ab72-834b-4c81-82b1-0d2760ea96b0" :QUANTITY
  4))
```

Ok, with all that said, lets look at unpacking it, let's say I want a list of the ID's from the `collection` table where the `user_id` is 1.

```
(loop :for row :in (mito:retrieve-by-sql (sxql:select (:id) (sxql:from :collection) (sxql:where (:= :user_id 1)))) :collect (getf row :ID))
=> (3828 4272 2710 4647 4502)
```

So considering you have a sxql string that represents what you want, it should be a simple matter of using `retrieve-by-sql` in the ways described above!